# Self referring structure declaration

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The follwing declaration is valid.

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *next;
};
```

However, when we define the following, it gives error.

```
"error: field ‘next’ has incomplete type"
```

Why is it so?

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node next; /* Not a pointer */   
};
```

Comment: Yes i have corrected that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node in `struct node` is a "struct tag", which at the point you write it creates an "incomplete type": a struct variable which is not at this point declared, but not defined. The type is not complete before the final `};` of your struct.

In C, an incomplete type can be referenced even before it is fully defined, by using a pointer to that type. You can however not allocate a variable (instance) of that type, because the actual struct definition is yet to be defined. (It works exactly like abstract base classes in C++, if you are familiar with those.)

So when you write

```
struct node {
  int a;
  struct node *next;
};
```

the row `struct node *next` means "here is a pointer to a struct node, even though I have no idea how that type is defined yet". But you cannot declare a variable of type `struct node` inside the struct definition of that very same type, simply because you cannot use something before you have created it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have structure that contains itself as a member:

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node next;
};
```

Think about this question: if it is possible, what is the size of such structure? `struct node` contains `struct node next` as a member, then the member `next` would contain a member of type `struct node` as well, and so on and on and on... The size would be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Your second declaration would define a struct which is infinitely deeply nested, which is impossible.

Comment: Actually my question is if there is no error in pointer type declaration, why the error in declaring the structure?

Comment: The first declaration is valid, as a pointer has constant size regardless of the referred structure. On the other hand, it is impossible to have a struct nested in itself as the resulting structure would be of infinite size.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same case as with forward declaration of class/struct type:

```
struct node;

struct node* node_ptr; /* is valid */
struct node node_instance; /* is invalid */
```

So `struct node;` basically says: hey there is a structure defined somewhere outside this file. The type is valid, pointers may be used, but you cannot instantiate the object.

This is because the size of the pointer is known and is specific to the target architecture (e.g. 32 or 64-bit). The size of the structure is unknown until declared.

When you declare the type completey, then you will be allowed to declare the object of that type:

```
struct node {
  int a;
  struct node* b; /* this will work, but the size of struct is unknown yet */
}

struct node* node_ptr; /* this works always with full and forward declarations */
struct node node_object; /* now, the size of struct is known, so the instance may be created */
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
struct node {
  int a;
  struct node *next;
};
```

this works,

but

```
struct node {
  int a;
  struct node next;
};
```

cannot be understood by the compiler as `node` becomes recursive structure, and the compiler does not know how much memory to allocate for `node`.

However, if you use a pointer, it understands that the size of a pointer is equal to size of the memory to be addressed, and hence reserves that space, regardless of if `node` is a complete struct.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer store address, struct has structure. If declared like struct it would be recursive and infinite. If declared like pointer it refers to other structure somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite nodes inside a node? Does that make sense? What will be the size of "struct node"?